# Make a function return class type

Tags: c++, class

I have a struct named Duration, how would I change this function so it would return an object of type Duration? and another question is if I have to overload the function how would I make it accept a duration object ?

```
void all(clock_t t, int &hours, int &minutes, int &seconds, int &ticks) {
    ticks = t % CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    seconds = t / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    minutes = seconds / 60;
    seconds %= 60;
    hours = minutes / 60;
    minutes %= 60;
}
```

Comment: Depends on the definition of `Duration`. It `Duration` consists of those fields, just return the created duration.

Comment: You should get some introductory book on C++.

Comment: do I have to make a new object inside the function? or do i pass the object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets say your `Duration` structure is like this:

```
struct Duration {
   int hours, minutes, seconds, ticks;
};
```

Now your `all()` method may look like this:

```
Duration all(clock_t t) {
    Duration duration;
    duration.ticks = t % CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    duration.seconds = t / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    duration.minutes = duration.seconds / 60;
    duration.seconds %= 60;
    duration.hours = duration.minutes / 60;
    duration.minutes %= 60;
    return duration;
}
```

And be called like this:

```
clock_t t = ...;
Duration duration = all(t);
```

To answer your other question, if you want to overload `all()` to accept a `Duration` for output, it can look like this:

```
void all(clock_t t, Duration &duration) {
    duration.ticks = t % CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    duration.seconds = t / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    duration.minutes = duration.seconds / 60;
    duration.seconds %= 60;
    duration.hours = duration.minutes / 60;
    duration.minutes %= 60;
}
```

And be called like this:

```
clock_t t = ...;
Duration duration;
all(t, duration);
```

If you overload, you can implement one overload using the other to reduce duplicating code, like this:

```
Duration all(clock_t t) {
    Duration duration;
    duration.ticks = t % CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    duration.seconds = t / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    duration.minutes = duration.seconds / 60;
    duration.seconds %= 60;
    duration.hours = duration.minutes / 60;
    duration.minutes %= 60;
    return duration;
}

void all(clock_t t, Duration &duration) {
    duration = all(t);
}
```

Or this:

```
void all(clock_t t, Duration &duration) {
    duration.ticks = t % CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    duration.seconds = t / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    duration.minutes = duration.seconds / 60;
    duration.seconds %= 60;
    duration.hours = duration.minutes / 60;
    duration.minutes %= 60;
}

Duration all(clock_t t) {
    Duration duration;
    all(t, duration);
    return duration;
}
```